# Webkit-scrollbar is causing a loss of focus (hover) between the menu and submenu

Tags: html, jquery, css, sass

I am trying to build a menu with two levels. It works like any other menu: when you hover over navigation menu item, an unordered list of submenus opens. However, when I move the pointer to the right, as soon as it reaches the vertical scrollbar, the submenu disappears. I can simply use "overflow-y: auto" and no webkit-scrollbar, but then I can't style the scrollbar.
Is there any way to have a styled scrollbar and still be able to reach the submenu without it disappearing?
It can be done in JS, jQuery, SCSS—any solution is welcome.

[image]

The code is simple:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
    Menu item 1
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-children">
                 <li class="dropdown-item">
                                <a href="/node/23">Submenu item 1</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="dropdown-item">
                                <a href="/node/23">Submenu item 2</a>
                 </li>
          </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
    Menu item 2
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-children">
                 <li class="dropdown-item">
                                <a href="/node/23">Submenu item 1</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="dropdown-item">
                                <a href="/node/23">Submenu item 2</a>
                 </li>
          </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and scss for styling:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  min-height: 4rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;

  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
     }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 10px;
     }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #0039FF;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
}
```

Comment: how'd you displaying `sub-menus` add code for that too.